# SQL Query tests not passing through

Tags: mysql, sql

I was presented with this question during a technical test in HackerRank, I made several attempts to answer it and even asked a friend who's much more experienced than me

[image: test]

This is the code we ended up submitting:

```
SELECT  name, count(*)     
FROM employee
GROUP BY name, phone, age
HAVING COUNT(*) >1;
```

Using dummy data, I was getting the accurate result on MySQL workbench.

[image: test2]

Is my query wrong? is the request poorly written? How can this be solved more efficiently (if possible at all)?

Comment: Dummy data? Tell me more.

Comment: The query in your screenshot and the query in your question are not the same.

Comment: Clumsy schema designer, storing age. (Most people get older each year, and the stored age values will soon be out-of-date. Store DOB instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is nearly correct, given the explanation of the requirments. But I have to say, what a terrible example of a question for this type of problem - please do not design schemas like this for your employer!

I say nearly correct since the actual requirement is just the names of the employees, so techincally you do not need to return the count(*) to satisfy the requirments.